# Retrieve users address using core location

Tags: swift, swift2, core-location

So I've been trying to retrieve the users location as an ADDRESS from the press of a button.

I can't seem to find any up to date examples that will work with SWIFT 2.

My best find so far has been [this website here (Get your current address in Swift)](http://rshankar.com/get-your-current-address-in-swift/), which is exactly what i want. Though i am getting a lot of errors as its a little out of date and i am not experienced enough to convert it.

This seems to be the only example that cuts out a lot of unnecessary converting coordinates to get the address that I've seen in other threads? Either way it just directly gets to what I'm trying to achieve.

Is anyone able to help me convert this code to an updated version?

This is a shot of the errors i am getting from the code in the link.
[image: Screenshot of errors]

EDIT: Working now and this is how it looks.
[image: solution]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is not out of date, it's just a bad copy paste job.

The `&gt;`s in the code need to be changed to `>` for example.

I suggest you read the Apple docs about the methods being used. And write the code out by hand instead of copy-pasting.

Comment: Thanks a lot i managed to get it happening, ill update my question soon with what i got